# how controling A Clickable pictureBox ?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a pictureBox and I want to perform a some statement when the image is clicked, So how can i check when the pictureBox is selected inside an if statement ?

Comment: Do you want some code to run when a user clicks the picturebox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an event handler to the `MouseClick` event, and then add in the code you want to run within the handler method:

`MyPictureBox.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(MyEventHandler);`

```
private void MyEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```